# Is there a quick lookup for url-to-controller mapping when @RequestMapping is used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

Given a web app that completely uses @RequestMapping to tie urls to a controller, I was wondering if there is a way or plug-in that would produce the web app's complete url-to-controller mappings?

Similar to struts.xml where you have all the urls mapping to an action hence you can see these information in a central place?

Otherwise, what happens is given a url from the screen, I end up doing a java file search each time I want to lookup that url's controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse has plugin Springsource Tool Suite (you can also download it standalone): http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts You must first add Spring project nature to your project, then switch to Java EE perspective and then you will see "Spring Elements" in your project and there you will see all request mappings (and much more).

edit: useful features like this in STS made me switch from NetBeans to Eclipse.

Comment: You're right, right under my nose! The thing though, as I tried now, my Spring Explorer view is saying my beans have errors that need to be resolved, but the project works fine though, I mean I can run the project and there are no errors. Probably just the IDE error... I'll proceed to tinkering this to make it work, but yes there is even an @RequestMapping view. Hopefully, I can make it to work soon.

Comment: Try refreshing your project (F5) and/or restarting Eclipse. Also if you have more Spring configuration files, STS needs to have them "groupped together" using a Config Set - see project properties -> Spring -> Beans Support. You can also disable some warnings/errors in project properties -> Spring.

Comment: Just in case somebody is still looking for that wonderful Spring view: "Spring Elements" are not shown in Package Explorer - you must switch to Project Explorer to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wire the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and extract all mappings. Something like:

```
@Autowired
// org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
private DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;

public void outputMappings() {
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : 
    defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.getHandlerMap().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "->" + 
                           entry.getValue().getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

See [`AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerMap()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.html#getHandlerMap%28%29) and [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html)